# Why does this sub-query do a table scan?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two queries, which are essentially identical in that the list of IDs (primary key) are the result of one of the queries --

[image]

It seems crazy that it is doing a full table scan for that query when it seems to should just search via the PK in the sub-query, and then search (again) for the PK in the outer query.

Why is mysql's execution plan doing this? Is there any way to fix it, other than do a pre-fetch of the ids -- that is, two queries instead of one?

Comment: Your query is all of 3 short-ish lines. WHy go to all the trouble of making an unreadable screenshot when you could've cut/paste the actual query text almost instantly?

Comment: I believe MySQL has issues taking advantages of indexes when ORs are involved. `UNION`s of near duplicate `SELECT`s (and differing conditions) are usually the solution to that. Also, when applicable, `JOIN`s tend to perform better than subselects in `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: You have plenty high enough rep to understand how to properly write a question.  This screenshot is unreadable at best...

Comment: what is your output when you run `show create table main_iteminstance`

Comment: A better question is "How fast does my query run, and is it worth my time micromanaging the SQL optimizer?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A table scan can be the fastest method of look up, especially if your entire table is cached in RAM (which usually is the case).

When the table is in memory, and the index is not, or not fully, it's cheaper to do the scan rather than load the index off the hard drive.

Try updating the stats on the tables and see if you get the same result.

```
ANALYZE TABLE table_name;
```

You should probably post things like the mysql version and table structure as well in order to help further.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify for MySQL what index will be used with [FORCE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html). It is not very elegant, but in rare cases, this decision will be justified.